# Why doesn't Django serve static files when the dubug=False in settings?

Tags: django

when I tried to run the project, static files are missing, and the settings.debug is set to False.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/deployment/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually in Django, while you run your project on the development server it won't serve your static files when you try to serve the static files after changing DEBUG settings to False. It will work properly on the production or stagging server but not on localhost server.
Still, there is a way to do this you can get by running your development server on insecure mode.

Try this,

```
python manage.py runserver --insecure
```

Answer (score 2):

Django does not serve static files in production (when `DEBUG = False`) because doing so would be in their own words (As stated in the section [Serving static files during development](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development) of the documentation):

> This method is **grossly inefficient** and probably **insecure**, so
> it is **unsuitable for production**.

Why is this inefficient one might say? Well static files are mostly larger in size than your normal HTML files, plus a website is bound to have **lots** of static files. If Django served static content even in production much of the time of the server would be wasted in serving these static files. Plus to serve multiple requests at the same time we run multiple Django processes simultaneously, if there are many requests for static files this will cause the processes to waste time serving them, causing other requests to wait if there are no free processes.

Plus as [@Reda Bourial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67570885/why-doesnt-django-serve-static-files-when-the-dubug-false-in-settings/67571103?noredirect=1#comment119436553_67571103) mentions in their comment Django doesn't handle compression well (One would want to compress their static files so that less bandwidth is required, both by the server and the client). Furthermore Django should focus more on the task it is designed for, which is rendering the pages requested by users (A CPU bound task), whereas serving static files is mostly just an Input / Output (I/O) task and for Django to spend time on these tasks (even when it is not efficient at them) is clearly a waste.

Servers like NGINX or Apache can serve static files much more efficiently, hence it is best to use them in production instead of having Django do it. For details on how to configure static files for production see [Deploying static files [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/deployment/)

Comment: I would also add that django doesn't handle compression well and the fact this would mix cpu bound workloads (page rendering...) with i/o bound ones (serve static stuff) so not a good idea ...

Answer (score 1):

it is not recommended, but if you are just getting started and want to understand more about what's going on, then you can also link directly:

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin

from djangoapp import settings
from webtools.views import *
from django.urls import path, include

"""
direct link on the server in production 
"""
from django.views.static import serve as mediaserve
from django.conf.urls import url


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),  
    path('', include('webtools.urls')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    import debug_toolbar
    urlpatterns = [
        path('__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
    ] + urlpatterns
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
else:
    # direct link on server in production
    urlpatterns += [
        url(f'^{settings.MEDIA_URL.lstrip("/")}(?P<path>.*)$', mediaserve, {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
        url(f'^{settings.STATIC_URL.lstrip("/")}(?P<path>.*)$', mediaserve, {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
    ]
```

settings.py:

```
DEBUG = False
.
.
.
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = []

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```